# Problemas ao criar jar executável com biblioteca JLayer no Intellij

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea, intellij

Boa tarde pessoal. Aí vai minha dúvida:

Estou criando um aplicativo simples para desktop em java 8 com swing no Intellij. Ao final de algumas modificações eu criava um *.jar* executável e até esse ponto tudo certo.

A partir de hoje estou utilizando uma biblioteca externa para reprodução de áudio chamada [JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) que roda perfeitamente na aplicação (quando lanço diretamente pela IDE Intellij). Porém agora que vou gerar um *jar* executável da mesma forma que sempre, ao executar o aplicativo (o jar executável) o player de som não funciona.

O problema parece que é claro: Eu não estou exportando a biblioteca *JLayer* externa que meu aplicativo precisa junto com o *jar* que estou gerando. Será que estou pensando correto? E se sim, como posso gerar esse executável no Intellij que empacote também essa biblioteca que preciso?

Answer (score 2):

Já resolvi o problema. Eis abaixo como:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Na IDE Intellij:
File -> Project Structure… -> Artifacts

Em “Avaliable Elements” tinha a library que eu necessitava. Mas eu clicava com o botão direito em cima da library e escolhia “Put Into Output Root” e não funcionava.
Então escolhi “Extract Into Output Root” e agora funcionou.